# Finding the median of two sorted arrays in logarithmic time

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to understand [this solution](http://www.programcreek.com/2012/12/leetcode-median-of-two-sorted-arrays-java/) to the problem of finding the medians of two sorted arrays:

```
public static double findMedianSortedArrays(int A[], int B[]) {
    int m = A.length;
    int n = B.length;

    if ((m + n) % 2 != 0) // odd
        return (double) findKth(A, B, (m + n) / 2, 0, m - 1, 0, n - 1);
    else { // even
        return (findKth(A, B, (m + n) / 2, 0, m - 1, 0, n - 1) 
            + findKth(A, B, (m + n) / 2 - 1, 0, m - 1, 0, n - 1)) * 0.5;
    }
}

public static int findKth(int A[], int B[], int k, 
    int aStart, int aEnd, int bStart, int bEnd) {

    int aLen = aEnd - aStart + 1;
    int bLen = bEnd - bStart + 1;

    // Handle special cases
    if (aLen == 0)
        return B[bStart + k];
    if (bLen == 0)
        return A[aStart + k];
    if (k == 0)
        return A[aStart] < B[bStart] ? A[aStart] : B[bStart];

    int aMid = aLen * k / (aLen + bLen); // a's middle count
    int bMid = k - aMid - 1; // b's middle count

    // make aMid and bMid to be array index
    aMid = aMid + aStart;
    bMid = bMid + bStart;

    if (A[aMid] > B[bMid]) {
        k = k - (bMid - bStart + 1);
        aEnd = aMid;
        bStart = bMid + 1;
    } else {
        k = k - (aMid - aStart + 1);
        bEnd = bMid;
        aStart = aMid + 1;
    }

    return findKth(A, B, k, aStart, aEnd, bStart, bEnd);
}
```

The first part that I cannot understand is how aMid and bMid defined in the findKth method represent A and B's middle counts. I went through a couple of examples by hand and I could see that, indeed, after comparing A[aMid] to B[bMid], only half of the total number of elements remained. But what is the idea behind the definition of these two indexes? Why are there only half the elements remaining after the comparison of A[aMid] and B[bMid]? Can anyone please explain me this solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say A[] = {1,5,6,7,8,9} and B[] = {2,3,4}, so the median of A[] and B[] should be 5, let's walk through the code.

1. findMedianSortedArrays(A, B), m=6, n=3
2. findKth(A, B, 4, 0, 5, 0, 2)

   - aMid=6*4/(6+3)=2, bMid=4-2-1=1, as a[2]=6>b[1]=3, so k=4-(1-0+1)=2, aEnd=2, bStart=2
3. findKth(A, B, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2)

   - aMid=3*2/(3+1)=1, bMid=2-1-1=0, as A[1]=5>B[bMid+bStart]=B[2]=4, so k=2-(2-2+1)=1, aEnd=1, bStart=3
4. findKth(A, B, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2)

   - bLen=0, return A[aStart+k]=A[0+1]=A[1]=5

---

So the overall idea is:

1. According to the weight of the array length, get the possible `median` of the array. (refer to aMid and bMid)
2. Compare A[aMid] and B[bMid], if (A[aMid] > B[bMid]), that means:

   - For all the elements in B[bStart..bMid], it should be in the left of the median, that's the easy part
   - And for all the elements in A[aMid+1..aEnd], it should be in the right of the median. That's because (aMid-aStart + bMid-bStart) already equal to (aLen+bLen)/2, and there may be extra elements in B[aMid+1..aEnd] that in left of array median.
   - So we reduce both of the array to half size, that's the reason run time complexity should be O(log (m+n)).
3. So recursive to find the midian in A[aStart..aMid] and B[bMid+1..bEnd].

Answer (score 0):

Basic way for java;

```
  public double findMedianSortedArrays(int[] nums1, int[] nums2) {
        double res;
        int arr[] = new int[nums1.length+nums2.length];
        
        for(int i= 0; i<nums1.length; i++){            
            arr[i] = nums1[i];
        }
        
        for(int i = nums1.length, j = 0; i<nums1.length+nums2.length; i++, j++){            
            arr[i] = nums2[j];
        }
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        if(arr.length == 1)res = arr[0];
        else {
            
            if(arr.length % 2 == 0)res = ((arr[arr.length/2]+arr[(arr.length/2)-1])/2.0);
            else{
                res = arr[(arr.length/2)];
            }
            
        }
        
        return res;
        
    }
```